# My qtopengl widget not showing up?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5

main.cpp

```
#include "QtGuiApplication4.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "megui.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    megui test;
    test.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

qtguiapplication4.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_QtGuiApplication4.h"

class QtGuiApplication4 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtGuiApplication4(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::QtGuiApplication4Class ui;
};
```

qtguiapplication4.cpp

```
#include "QtGuiApplication4.h"

QtGuiApplication4::QtGuiApplication4(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}
```

megui.h

```
#pragma once
#include "QOpenGLWidget"
#include "QOpenGLBuffer"
#include "QOpenGLFunctions"
#include "QOpenGLShaderProgram"
#include <iostream>
class megui:public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
public:
    QOpenGLFunctions glfunctions;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram program;

    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();

    megui();
    ~megui();
};
```

megui.cpp

```
#include "megui.h"

void megui::initializeGL()
{
    makeCurrent();
    float vertexpositions[] = {
        0.5f,0.5f,
        0.0f,-0.5f,
        0.5f,-0.5f
    };
    QOpenGLBuffer buffer1(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
    buffer1.create();
    buffer1.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    buffer1.allocate(vertexpositions, sizeof(vertexpositions));
    buffer1.bind();
    glfunctions.initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glfunctions.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glfunctions.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, "C:/open gl testimg/opengl testing/opengl testing/vertex.glsl");
    program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, "C:/open gl testimg/opengl testing/opengl testing/fragmentshader.glsl");
    program.link();
}

void megui::paintGL()
{
    makeCurrent();

    glfunctions.initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    program.bind();
    glfunctions.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);   
}

megui::megui()
{
}

megui::~megui()
{
}
```

fragmentshader

```
#version 430

out vec4 inalcolors;

void main() {

    inalcolors =vec4( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,1.0) ;
}
```

vertexshader

```
#version 430 

layout(location = 0) in vec4 positions;

void main() {

    gl_Position =positions; 
}
```

The widget screen is not showing up but when i remove **glDrawArrays** call then it shows up.I suspect there is some problem in the opengl code which is causing this.I followed a youtube tutorial everything in his and my code is same expect i use qt opengl wrapper class rather than glew library.what would be the reason?

Comment: sorry, I have added shader code and program.bind.it still doesn't work

Comment: `makeCurrent()` can be [omitted](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#details) - your widget's OpenGL rendering context is made current when `paintGL()`, `resizeGL()`, or `initializeGL()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `QOpenGLBuffer buffer1` is a local variable in the method `megui::initializeGL()`. Qt OpenGL objects uses [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization (RAII)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) technology. This means at the end of the function `buffer1` is destructed and the buffer is gone and invalid.

Further the `QOpenGLBuffer` object has to be bound (`bind()`) **before** it can be allocated (`allocate()`). See the documentation of [`QOpenGLBuffer::allocate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglbuffer.html#allocate).

By the way, your vertex coordinates consists of 2 components (x, y) and not of 3.

Create a `QOpenGLBuffer` member in the class `megui`

```
class megui:public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
public:
    QOpenGLFunctions glfunctions;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram program;

    QOpenGLBuffer buffer1;

    .....
}
```

```
megui::megui()
    : buffer1(QOpenGLBuffer::VertexBuffer)
{}
```

Bind the buffer before you allocate it:

```
void megui::initializeGL()
{
    .....

    buffer1.create();
    buffer1.setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);

    buffer1.bind(); // <-------- bind before allocate
    buffer1.allocate(vertexpositions, sizeof(vertexpositions));


    float vertexpositions[] = {
        0.5f,0.5f,
        0.0f,-0.5f,
        0.5f,-0.5f
    };

    glfunctions.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glfunctions.glVertexAttribPointer(
        0, 2,       // <-------- 2 instead of 3
        GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    buffer1.release();

    .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works  but i still don't know the reason why widget screen is not showing up.is it if paintgl call fails the window disappear?

Comment: @karansharma In the code of your question the buffer is destroyed, before it is used and the widget crashes.